# How to display all decimal values for arithmetic operations?

Tags: .net, vb.net, decimal

a part of my code computes for the product of two numbers, the result being stored to a variable declared as decimal, the problem is when I try to display the result to a textbox it does not show the whole value of the result.

```
Dim value1 As Integer = 1576000
Dim value2 As double = 7620.22
Dim result As Decimal

result = value1 / value2    ''result from a calculator is 206.81817585319059029....

textBox1.text = result.ToString  ''textbox displays 206.818175853191
```

From what I have searched decimal data types can hold up to 28-29 decimal place, but when the result is displayed it is converted to double(data type).

Also, `result = value1 / value2` is the whole value of result stored to the memory?

Comment: [Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are computing a double value and assigning its value and precision to a Decimal variable.

If your code was setup with `Option Strict On` the IDE would have given you a clue to what is going on.  With `Option Strict On`, this statement:

`result = value1 / value2`

would give the error:

> Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Double' to 'Decimal'

Doubles have 15 significant digits.  If you count the number of digits in `206.818175853191` you will see that there are 15 digits (the decimal mark does not count).

To get the desired result, perform the division with Decimal values.

`Dim result2 As Decimal = CDec(value1) / CDec(value2)`

Comment: whenever I try to change all the variable type to decimal and with (Option Strict On), value2 gives an error " Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Double' to 'Decimal' "; why does this error appear, is the value out of the range for a decimal data type?

can you share more information about these data types cause I need to use them on computations where I need to preserve as many decimal.

Comment: @AnitoLabs, Use the syntax shown in the answer, there will be no error if the values being converted to Decimal are within the range limits of the Decimal type.  I will not spoon feed you a tutorial on basic programming and type conversion. You should familiarize yourself with the language and there are many sources of that information readily available.  Start with either the online [Visual Basic Language Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sh9ywfdk.aspx) or download the [Visual Basic Language Specification 11.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15039).

Comment: @AnitoLabs, In general, when you work with Option Strict Off, you are essentially telling the compiler "Please make me feel good about my code and compile this mess.  I don't care about accuracy or speed.  All that matters is that my ego is spared from being told that my code stinks."  The compiler will then do its best to honor that request by trying to find a way to rewrite the code with explicit type conversions that satisfy the target type.  This rewriting of the code often results in a completely illogical mess that will run, but with unexpected results.